# How to solve this traceback error in pdfquery

Tags: python

I'm getting following error when I try try to execute tests.py in pdfquery

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\workspace-php\test\pdfminer\pdfminer\tests.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pdfquery
  File "C:\workspace-php\test\pdfminer\pdfminer\pdfquery.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pyquery import PyQuery
  File "C:\workspace-php\test\pdfminer\pdfminer\pyquery.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cssselectpatch import JQueryTranslator
  File "C:\workspace-php\test\pdfminer\pdfminer\cssselectpatch.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cssselect import xpath as cssselect_xpath
ImportError: No module named cssselect
```

Any body know which causes this error.

Comment: `ImportError: No module named cssselect`. Install cssselect module first.  http://pythonhosted.org/cssselect/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not look for a solution for the `Traceback` error. You look for the error at the bottom.

```
ImportError: No module named cssselect
```

The error suggests that the python interpreter could not find the cssselect library on your system. If the library is not installed on your machine, install it as per the instructions [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cssselect/0.9.1)

Comment: thanksi solved that ImportError: No module named cssselect error.Do u know how to call file in parent directory?

Comment: You can not call a file. You can call methods in that file after importing that as a module. This has info on it - https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: i still got another error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\workspace-php\test\pdfminer\pdfminer\pyquery.py", line 9, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: No module named lxml.I downloaded lxmk from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/2.2.8